# create a new column in pandas and assign value from existing column if condition is true

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, stock

I have 15 minutes candles of stock data and have a short signal - I want to create a new column stop-loss if signal=0 then stop-loss = high of the second next candle ie( df['high'].shift(-2) )

```
                        open     high      low    close  signal
date                                                           
2020-01-01 09:15:00  1452.50  1457.00  1449.20  1452.50     NaN
2020-01-01 09:30:00  1452.30  1454.40  1450.00  1451.45     NaN
2020-01-01 09:45:00  1450.50  1454.80  1450.00  1453.75     NaN
2020-01-01 10:00:00  1453.70  1453.70  1450.10  1450.70     0.0
2020-01-01 10:15:00  1450.70  1453.00  1450.50  1452.20     NaN
2020-01-01 10:30:00  1452.00  1452.00  1446.75  1446.85     NaN
2020-01-01 10:45:00  1447.60  1449.00  1445.50  1447.10     NaN
2020-01-01 11:00:00  1446.75  1449.00  1446.55  1447.65     NaN
```

in this example:
stop-loss for short signal at 2020-01-01 10:00:00 will be 1452.00
which is the High at  2020-01-01 10:30:00

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `np.where(condition, answer if condition is true, answer if condition is false)`

```
df['stop-loss']=np.where(df.signal==0,df.high.shift(-2),'')
```

In this case, you didnt specify what the condition should be if false so I put there `''`

```
                        open    high      low    close  signal stop-loss
date                                                                    
2020-01-01 09:15:00  1452.50  1457.0  1449.20  1452.50     NaN          
2020-01-01 09:30:00  1452.30  1454.4  1450.00  1451.45     NaN          
2020-01-01 09:45:00  1450.50  1454.8  1450.00  1453.75     NaN          
2020-01-01 10:00:00  1453.70  1453.7  1450.10  1450.70     0.0    1452.0
2020-01-01 10:15:00  1450.70  1453.0  1450.50  1452.20     NaN          
2020-01-01 10:30:00  1452.00  1452.0  1446.75  1446.85     NaN          
2020-01-01 10:45:00  1447.60  1449.0  1445.50  1447.10     NaN          
2020-01-01 11:00:00  1446.75  1449.0  1446.55  1447.65     NaN
```

Following your additional question in the comments. assume dataframe is

```
                  open    high      low    close  signal
date                                                          
2020-01-01 09:15:00  1452.50  1457.0  1449.20  1452.50     NaN
2020-01-01 09:30:00  1452.30  1454.4  1450.00  1451.45     NaN
2020-01-01 09:45:00  1450.50  1454.8  1450.00  1453.75     NaN
2020-01-01 10:00:00  1453.70  1453.7  1450.10  1450.70     0.0
2020-01-01 10:15:00  1450.70  1453.0  1450.50  1452.20     NaN
2020-01-01 10:30:00  1452.00  1452.0  1446.75  1446.85     1.0
2020-01-01 10:45:00  1447.60  1449.0  1445.50  1447.10     NaN
2020-01-01 11:00:00  1446.75  1449.0  1446.55  1447.65     NaN
```

Use `np.select([conditons],[choices], alternative)`

```
conditions=[df.signal==0,df.signal==1]
choices=[df.high.shift(-2),df.low.shift(-2)]
df['stop-loss']=np.select(conditions, choices,'')



                   open    high      low    close  signal stop-loss
date                                                                    
2020-01-01 09:15:00  1452.50  1457.0  1449.20  1452.50     NaN          
2020-01-01 09:30:00  1452.30  1454.4  1450.00  1451.45     NaN          
2020-01-01 09:45:00  1450.50  1454.8  1450.00  1453.75     NaN          
2020-01-01 10:00:00  1453.70  1453.7  1450.10  1450.70     0.0    1452.0
2020-01-01 10:15:00  1450.70  1453.0  1450.50  1452.20     NaN          
2020-01-01 10:30:00  1452.00  1452.0  1446.75  1446.85     1.0   1446.55
2020-01-01 10:45:00  1447.60  1449.0  1445.50  1447.10     NaN          
2020-01-01 11:00:00  1446.75  1449.0  1446.55  1447.65     NaN
```

Comment: what if I also had a Long signal 1, and stop-loss for that df.low.shift(-2) , is there a way to add both in np.where?

Comment: Please try np.select `conditions=[df.signal==0,df.signal==1]
choices=[df.high.shift(-2),df.low.shift(-2)]
df['stop-loss']=np.select(conditions, choices,'')`

Comment: did this help? If happy, please upvote for the answer so that others can confidently use your question and my answer in future.